# Is it possible to change the default install location of Modern UI apps?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

Is there a way to change where Modern UI apps get installed, to a different disk for example?

I tried looking in the **Settings** charm for the Store app, but there is no option in there.

Comment: Aside from faking it with directory junctions, I wouldn't consider this, due to the intended increased abstraction of the file system in Windows 8. It could change in later versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Randolph](https://superuser.com/users/3463/randolph-west) [says](https://superuser.com/questions/463369/is-it-possible-to-change-the-default-install-location-of-modern-ui-apps/491492#comment544310_463369), it's probably not a good idea to change it, but it is possible as described here:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/w8itprogeneral/thread/f5e33ac9-beab-4b99-b3ca-7cb5e6f415e4

> The registry key to set the directory for Metro apps is located at: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx`
>   You have the `PagckageRoot` key that sets the value.
>   I don't know if it's supported to change that value and/or if it will break anything, if you want to try it, it's at your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has stated that for the surface it would be impossible to install metro apps on the SD card, only Data. I think this answers your question too.

Comment: Would that be just the Surface RT? Because it would be far from impossible in the Surface Pro, quite easy to create a directory symlink or junction, as Randolph suggested, that by its very nature should work. I think the same should be possible in Windows RT as long as it is still using NTFS as its underlying filesystem, but that may require more hacking to create the symlink/junction.

Comment: It simply means for the average user it is not possible. Haven't played around with symlinks yet, good idea indeed! And that should work just as well on RT as on Pro (if it works).